# Getting library from windows media player - C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to build an interface to choose and play songs using a touch screen. So far the eaisest way I can find is to use WMP, the problem I have is getting the lists of artists, albums and songs and displaying them in list boxes from the WMP library.
Basically I have 3 list boxes. One needs to display artists, one albums and one songs. These need to come from WMP library. How can I achieve this?
Thanks heaps for any help.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the Playlist over the COM Interface. You just have to add the com library "WMPLib" and create a new instance of the player:

```cs
//create windows media player instance
WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayer();

//get all playlists and media
IWMPPlaylistArray paylists = wmp.playlistCollection.getAll();
IWMPPlaylist allMedia = wmp.mediaCollection.getAll();
```

Now you can iterate over thos lists to get the information you want to.

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to programming and still unsure how to do this. So I have say lstArtist, how would i set the collection for this list to be the list of artists from wmp? Thanks and sorry again for it having to be spelled out for me.